# SQL Server Database comparision tools

Tags: sql-server

I want to compare two SQL server database schemas, Views, SPs, UDFs, Triggers, Indexes etc. Is there any freeware available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

- [Free Database Compare](http://www.starinix.com/sqlcompare01.htm)
- [DBDiff on Codeplex](http://dbdiff.codeplex.com/)
- [Open DB Diff](http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/)
- [DBComparer](http://dbcomparer.com/)
- [xSQL DB Bundle - free Lite edition](http://www.xsqlsoftware.com/download.aspx)

[Here's a whole list](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/20/Free-SQL-Server-tools-that-might-make-your-life-a.aspx) of database freebies - not all link seems to still work, though...

Answer (score 0):

You could go for http://dbcomparer.com/ which is absolutely free and has all the features you are looking for, plus it supports sql server 2005 and 2008.